# Passing a parameter to a macro-enabled workbook through a .bat file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has a lot of different macros in it, as well as mapping files. I would like to create a .bat file that will open this workbook and run a specific macro.

I don't want this macro to run every time there is a workbook_open event, I only want it to run when the batch file says

```
"C:\~\Excel.exe" "c:\workbook1.xlsm" /Macro1
```

or something like that.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no command-line option for this. You could use a vbs file instead of a bat file: that would give you more control.

Comment: Another possibility is for the batch file to create a text file (Echo Macro1 >> workbook1.txt).  An Auto_Open macro within workbook1 can read this file, save its contents and then delete it.  uto_Open would then action the parameters within the file.  Note: Auto_Open is a Excel 2003 facility.  There may be better techniques for later versions of Excel.

Comment: A VBS file sounds like a good idea, but I can't figure out how to make it work. Can you please post a code sample for opening book1.xlsm and running Macro1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vbs script might look something like this if I understood correctly - you can add variables for filenames and error handling yourself, I guess.

```
Sub RunAMacro(strMacroName$)
    Dim oExcel as Object
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
    oExcel.Workbooks.Open "c:\path\to\file.xls"
    oExcel.Run strMacroName 'This is the name of the macro
    ' decide here if you need to save, or just close, or whatever
    oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    oExcel.ActiveWindow.Close
    oExcel.Quit
    Set oExcel = Nothing
End Sub

RunAMacro("YourMacroName")
```

Comment: Works perfectly, just needed to remove the $ sign and "as Object". Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've just edited the answer (after a few years...). The $strMacroName is PHP syntax for a variable, whereas `...(strMacroName$)` is essentially the same as `...(strMacroName as String)`